# CSS Nitpick: Line height of bullet points is smaller

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

For some reason (perhaps a good one that I am not aware of) the line-height of normal paragraph text (in posts), and the line-height of the text body of bullet points is different.

#### Examples

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vestibulum erat vitae velit tempus ut congue ante lacinia. Cras a ligula mi. Duis porttitor dui sed nisl condimentum et tristique lorem venenatis. In pharetra dignissim nisl, at hendrerit massa dignissim id. Vivamus commodo purus eget odio elementum et porttitor ante imperdiet.

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vestibulum erat vitae velit tempus ut congue ante lacinia. Cras a ligula mi. Duis porttitor dui sed nisl condimentum et tristique lorem venenatis. In pharetra dignissim nisl, at hendrerit massa dignissim id. Vivamus commodo purus eget odio elementum et porttitor ante imperdiet.

#### CSS

```
.post-text {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 130%; /* equivalent to 18.2px */
}

ol li, ul li {
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

The `130%/18px` from the paragraph CSS looks much better, in my humble opinion, and I think the bullet point should be set to match it.  I don't know why it's 16px right now but it looks more squashed together, and at the very least it looks weird when reading posts that use both bullet point paragraphs and normal paragraphs together (I admit this is somewhat in self-interest, it is a style I often use!)

Comment: You're right this is indeed a bug. I'm fixing now.

Comment: @Jin, cool, looks much better now.

Answer (score 1):

The fix will be in the next deployment.